# Adding a switch to UITableViewCell: storyboard vs code

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to add a UISwitch to my settings view controller. The switch looks identically to Airplane Mode toggle in the 'Settings' app on iOS. I'm not sure about what is the best way to implement this.

I am choosing between:

1. adding a UISwitch in code
2. creating a custom cell in the Storyboard and creating an outlet for a switch

Here's my Swift code for adding a switch to UITableViewCell:

```
let soundSwitch = UISwitch(frame: CGRectZero)
soundSwitch.addTarget(self, action: "test:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
// I created an outlet for the cell that will contain a switch
soundCell.accessoryView = tickingSoundSwitch
```

What are advantages and disadvantages of using these solutions?

Comment: Why dont you add UISwitch in storyBoard and create an IBAction for it??? instead of adding target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use either

**1.UISwitch in storyboard along with an IBAction**  , if you use this approach things becomes easy ,you need not to add target and mess with lot of codes.

or

**2.Completely rely on code**, Using this approach your UISwitch will not get tight coupled with storyboard's UI. Even in the future if you want to change the UI stuffs in storyboard you need not to do any changes for your UISWitch ,i.e you don't need to  attach all those IBAction and outlet stuffs as you are using pure code based approach(provided your UISwitch requirement doesn't change).

Comment: That certainly makes sense. I think I'll go with the first solution, completely forgot about IBAction's. Thanks!

Comment: Dan, it's my pleasure :)